# What can i put into Vuex state?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

All the examples show that the initial state is an object. Can I put an array or a string into the state?

```
{
  state: [], // just an array or string
  mutations: { 
    add(state, { name }) {
      return [...state, { name }];
    } 
  },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}
```

This way I won't be able to set properties on the state, instead just return the current state inside a mutation

Comment: The vuex state should be an object. Why don't you tell us what you are actually trying to do with vuex?

Comment: No. The state of an application usually manages many data points. If you only want to manage one data point in your application Vuex is probably overkill. You could always  manage this one datapoint in your root component.

Comment: I want to use modules...and for one datatype which is a list, I cant use a module, I have to wrap it with an object

Comment: Plus mutation seems ugly in a reducer function...you can skip mutation in Angular and Redux, just return the actual state